# How to read content of file from SharePoint list given under link

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I have a list in my SharePoint which contains lots of metadata and having multiple list item along with a link of a file.

Doc_name, Author, Modified_Date, Document_Link

I am able to read all metadata but I also want to read the content of the file in the stream. For that, I need a c# function which will go to the link for each listitem, read the content and return me a file stream. plz help..

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please provide some code and specify a particular issue or problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for your reference(Document_Link is hyperlink field), the link points to same web, if your link points to other web/site, need init ClientContext for target site collection.

```
using(var context=new ClientContext("http://sp"))
            {
                var web = context.Web;
                var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
                var item = list.GetItemById(1);
                context.Load(web);
                context.Load(item);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                var fileLink = item["Document_Link"] as FieldUrlValue;

                var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileLink.Url.Replace(web.Url,""));
                context.Load(file);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                //to do
                //var stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }
```

Comment: Your solution helped me up to some extent. Rest all I have modified. Thanks a lot for your help. It was helpful..  Cheers

Comment: You could accept it as answer or share your work code to help others.